# Puppet installs redundant java 7

Tags: java, puppet

I have puppet to install java 8 and tomcat 8 on my debian vms. Installation is successful with only one problem. Puppet installs java 7 together with 8. Alternatives are correctly set to java 8. Do you have any idea how to get rid of this redundant java?

```
class sh::java ($version = 'latest') {
  exec { "update-package-list":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
  }

  package { 'openjdk-8-jre-headless':
    ensure   => $version,
    require  => Exec["update-package-list"],
  }
}

class sh::tomcat8 {
  class { 'tomcat':
    group => 'tomcat8',
    user  => 'tomcat8',
  }

  tomcat::instance { 'tomcat8':
    catalina_base => '/var/lib/tomcat8',
    install_from_source => false,
    package_ensure      => 'present',
    package_name        => 'tomcat8'
  }->
  tomcat::instance { 'tomcat8-admin':
    install_from_source => false,
    package_ensure      => 'present',
    package_name        => 'tomcat8-admin'
  }->
  tomcat::config::server::tomcat_users { 'bamboo-user':
    ensure       => 'present',
    catalina_base => '/var/lib/tomcat8',
    element      => 'user',
    element_name => 'bamboo',
    password     => 'bamboo',
    roles        => ['manager-script', 'manager-gui'],
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the Puppetlabs Java module to install java?

You could replace the top bit of code with just: `class {'::java'}`

Comment: Run puppet in debug mode `-d`, and look for the output of your package manager to see where java7 gets installed. Could your install of tomcat be requiring java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debian tomcat8 package has a dependency on **openjdk-7-jre-headless**.

Manual install confirms this:

```
root@debian-jessie:~# apt-get install tomcat8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  authbind ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless java-common libasyncns0 libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java libflac8 libice6 libnspr4 libnss3 libogg0 libpcsclite1 libpulse0
  libsctp1 libsm6 libsndfile1 libtomcat8-java libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 lksctp-tools openjdk-7-jre-headless tomcat8-common tzdata-java x11-common
Suggested packages:
  default-jre equivs libcommons-dbcp-java-doc libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java ecj ant libecj-java-gcj pcscd pulseaudio icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libnss-mdns sun-java6-fonts fonts-dejavu-extra
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei ttf-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic libtcnative-1 tomcat8-admin tomcat8-docs tomcat8-examples tomcat8-user
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  authbind ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless java-common libasyncns0 libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java libflac8 libice6 libnspr4 libnss3 libogg0 libpcsclite1 libpulse0
  libsctp1 libsm6 libsndfile1 libtomcat8-java libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 lksctp-tools openjdk-7-jre-headless tomcat8 tomcat8-common tzdata-java x11-common
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

So when puppet installs tomcat8 deb package you are also getting java 7.

Some options:

Get puppet to install tomcat8 from source instead of the debian
   package to prevent the dependency on java 7.

```
tomcat::instance { 'tomcat8':
  catalina_base       => '/var/lib/tomcat8',
  install_from_source => true,
  package_ensure      => 'present',
  package_name        => 'tomcat8'
}
```

Or install from the deb package and get puppet to remove java 7:

```
package { 'openjdk-7-jre-headless':
  ensure => absent,
}
```

A side note:
As mentioned in the comments, [java module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/java) could also be used to install java 8 and the [apt module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) could also be used rather than the exec to manage the apt updates.